# Unable to retrieve ethereum address from the signed data

Tags: web3js, metamask, javascript

I used the `web3.eth.accounts.recover` method to retrieve the ethereum address but I am getting an error. Here is the code:

```
  let v = '0x' + signed_nonce.slice(130,134);
  let r = signed_nonce.slice(0,66);
  let s = '0x' + signed_nonce.slice(66,130);

  // recover public key from hashed nonce
  let public_key = web3.eth.accounts.recover({
    messageHash: sh3_nonce,
    v: v,
    r: r,
    s: s
  });
```

The error I am getting is :

```
TypeError: Object ws://localhost:8546 has no method 'send'
```

But it works perfectly fine when I manually enter the address.
Eg: when I give it as  `let public_key =0x3f969A63aD4c112345E7541A5eF74C7123477696`, it shows up no error.

Comment: You should possibly connect via HTTP instead of via WebSocket (if you share how you initialize the `web3` object, then it might help to determine).

Comment: Side note: Your logical analysis isn't worth much, since `let public_key =0x3f969A63aD4c112345E7541A5eF74C7123477696` would never show an error (unless `public_key ` has already been declared in this scope, but I'm guessing that's not what it's all about). You could just as well say that the error is in `web3.eth.accounts.recover` (which you have done so already).

Comment: @goodvibration I initialised web3 like this: `const web3 = new Web3(Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546");`

Comment: Looks pretty bad to me. Why don't you check `typeof Web3.givenProvider`, and then think what is the meaning of ORing this type and a string type.?

Comment: Isn't that the prescribed way of initialising Web3?

Comment: Not sure what you mean be `prescribed`, but obviously there is more than one way to instantiate a `Web3` object. In any case, you should understand the meaning of `Web3.givenProvider || "ws://localhost:8546"` if you choose to use it. You can start by checking the type of the first part of the expression, or even print the entire expression. I bet you'll see that this expression doesn't evaluate into a legitimate argument for the `Web3` constructor.